# AWS Identity Center Terraform Authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I wrote code on my personal AWS account and I could authenticate fine although I don't have Identity Center setup.

on my work AWS account, I have Identity Center setup and I have various accounts (dev, staging, live). I can retrieve the credentials by clicking ' Command line or programmatic access' but the credentials don't seem to authenticate. I'm not sure if I am using the right script to authenticate, as all I've done is change the access_key and secret_key, but I noticed there is a third key in identity center 'aws_session_token'

I put the script I am using below.

```
terraform {
 required_providers {
   aws = {
     source  = "hashicorp/aws"
     version = "~> 5.0"
   }
 }
}

provider "aws" {
 region     = "eu-west-2"
 access_key = "**"
 secret_key = "**"
}
```

I removed the access and secret key for security reasons.

**Error below**

```
Retrieving AWS account details: validating provider credentials: retrieving caller identity from STS: operation error STS: GetCallerIdentity, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: b633dba1-4cf1-41ec-81e7-07ae2b8d501b, api error InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.
│ 
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
│   on providers.tf line 10, in provider "aws":
│   10: provider "aws" {
│
```

Comment: Did you authenticate using `aws sso login`?

Comment: On Terraform or in AWS? If in AWS then yes. I authenticate using SSO login.

Comment: Well, there could be a couple of steps needed. The question remains: did you run `aws sso login` from the machine you are running terraform from? Are you using profiles or not?

Comment: in short, no. I did not run aws sso login. I didn't know I had to add that into my terraform script. I am not using profiles in AWS, I'm using accounts.

Comment: You don't need to add that to terraform. You run it outside of terraform. That will create temporary credentials and it may or may not work.